# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended with insert all

Tags: oracle, sql-insert

I cannot seem to find any problem:

```
INSERT ALL
   INTO DEPT_PART PARTITION(part1) (EMPNO, ENAME, SAL, DEPTNO) 
   SELECT EMPNO,ENAME,SAL,DEPTNO FROM emp WHERE DEPTNO=10

   INTO DEPT_PART PARTITION(part2) (EMPNO, ENAME, SAL, DEPTNO) 
   SELECT EMPNO,ENAME,SAL,DEPTNO FROM emp WHERE DEPTNO=20

   INTO DEPT_PART PARTITION(part3) (EMPNO, ENAME, SAL, DEPTNO) 
   SELECT EMPNO,ENAME,SAL,DEPTNO FROM emp WHERE DEPTNO=30

SELECT * FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: What is the partitioning key for DEPT_PART? Why do you need to specify the target partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to try `INSERT FIRST` like following:

```
INSERT FIRST
   WHEN DEPTNO = 10 THEN
   INTO DEPT_PART PARTITION(part1) (EMPNO, ENAME, SAL, DEPTNO) 
   WHEN DEPTNO = 20 THEN
   INTO DEPT_PART PARTITION(part2) (EMPNO, ENAME, SAL, DEPTNO) 
   WHEN DEPTNO = 30 THEN
   INTO DEPT_PART PARTITION(part3) (EMPNO, ENAME, SAL, DEPTNO) 
SELECT EMPNO,ENAME,SAL,DEPTNO FROM emp WHERE DEPTNO IN (10,20,30)
```

Cheers!!